# How to use regex to insert dynamic urls in the Analytics conversion funnel?

Tags: regex, google-analytics, e-commerce, velo, goal-tracking

A have a client who has an ecommerce website working on Wix. She asked me to setup the conversion funnel so she could identify when visitors leave a step, I mean, those who don't get to the order placed page. On Wix, we have 3 steps/urls, as below:

Cart: `https://www.easyhomedesign.com.br/cart?appSectionParams=%7B%22origin%22%3A%22cart-popup%22%7D`

Checkout: `https://www.easyhomedesign.com.br/checkout?appSectionParams=%7B%22a11y%22%3Afalse%2C%22cartId%22%3A%2283476f86-4ac9-44ac-8779-4479dde12cc2%22%2C%22storeUrl%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.easyhomedesign.com.br%2F%22%2C%22isFastFlow%22%3Afalse%2C%22isPickupFlow%22%3Afalse%7D`

and the Thank you page: `https://www.easyhomedesign.com.br/thank-you-page/d28bc342-0afe-40cb-8d98-a5784b6b2f17`

After each of those urls, we have dynamic string values, so I need to put into the funnel step, on the url field, those same urls but using a regex that matches to the config "starts with", since we can't know what the values on the end of the urls are and, on the funnel setup section, we don't have that combobox "Starts with". At least, that's the only solution I could think about.

Then, my idea is use something like `https://www.easyhomedesign.com.br/thank-you-page/$`. I don't know regex, that's only an example of what I thought about, since that part of the url is the fixed one.

Could someone help me? tks.

Answer (score 0):

Although the final goal setup highly depends on your Analyitcs implementation, it is basically possible to cover such funnel with RegEx in goal funnels.

Google Analytics tracks page visits with path, buy default. So `https://www.easyhomedesign.com.br/thank-you-page/d28bc342-0afe-40cb-8d98-a5784b6b2f17` will become `/thank-you-page/d28bc342-0afe-40cb-8d98-a5784b6b2f17` in your reports. It can be set up to contain the domain, and the goal flow can be created as well, but it's important to check, how the RegEx should be created.

It is also important, if the above mentioned query parts are affecting the step, whether they are part of the flow or not.

**Assuming that the path part is relevant, you can set up something like this.**

Cart URL in reports: `/cart?appSectionParams=%7B%22origin%22%3A%22cart-popup%22%7D`

Cart step RegEx in goal flow: `^\/cart`

`^` stands for beginning of the string, but you might need to adjust, if host is present in your reports. You can also extend it to `^\/cart\?`, if you expect any parameters to be present, to qualify for cart visit.

Checkout URL in reports: `/checkout?appSectionParams=%7B%22a11y%22%3Afalse%2C%22cartId%22%3A%2283476f86-4ac9-44ac-8779-4479dde12cc2%22%2C%22storeUrl%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.easyhomedesign.com.br%2F%22%2C%22isFastFlow%22%3Afalse%2C%22isPickupFlow%22%3Afalse%7D`

Checkout Cart step RegEx in goal flow: `^\/checkout`

The same applies for checkout step for beginning of the string, or for any parameters required.

Thank you URL in reports: `/thank-you-page/d28bc342-0afe-40cb-8d98-a5784b6b2f17`

Thank you RegEx, which is essentially the goal's RegEx: `^\/thank-you-page\/[\w-]+`

Here, the `[\w-]+` part expects alphanumerical characters, underscore, or hyphen to be present. More precisely, one or more must exist there.

The `$` sign, mentioned in the OP, could not be used here, as it indicates the end of the string, and therefore the id at the end of the URL would make it non-matching.